# PathParam Layer check REST

Tags: rest, query-string, path-parameter

First of all have a nice weekend for those who are! For the other good luck :)

I am creating an app using rest architecture.

I just have a simple question but I don't know how to explain it.

So let's take an example and maybe the question will come after.

Imagine you have a path element called Car. If I do a GET on it it returns the carInformation

So I would define:

```
@GET
@Path("/car/{carid}/display")
public Response getCar(@PathParam("carid")String carID)
```

If I define actions to perform on this car like open, close, start etc:

```
@POST
@Path("/car/{carid}/startup")
public Response startup(@PathParam("carid")String carID)

@POST
@Path("/car/{carid}/open")
public Response open(@PathParam("carid")String carID)

@POST
@Path("/car/{carid}/close")
public Response close(@PathParam("carid")String carID)
```

Is there a common check done at /car/{carid} like "is it my car?" "is it in the garage?" or do I have to implement it with abstraction for example between the process which will be called after

In fact I am not understanding the real goal of path param. Why don't do simply

```
@GET
@Path("/car/displayCar")
public Response getCar(@QueryParam("carid")String carID)

@POST
@Path("/car/startup")
public Response startup(String carID)

@POST
@Path("/car/{carid}/open")
public Response open(String carID)

@POST
@Path("/car/{carid}/close")
public Response close(String carID)
```

Thanks all for you answer in advance

Best regards

Geoffrey MUSELLI

Comment: So, for starters, this isn't a knock - just a clarification.  If you are defining actions in your URL then you are, in general, not designing a RESTful API.  You are talking RPC (not a bad thing, necessarily, just a difference in terminology.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to go at this, both REST and RPC - and I'm not here to say which is better (you need to evaluate which would be easier/better/etc for the consumers of your API [IMO]).  For this I am going to go at it using a REST approach.

For displaying a single car's info there is no need for an endpoint ending in 'display'.  A *GET* request to /car/{car id} is sufficient.  That document can have things like the car's current state (open, closed, running, exploded, etc . . .)  The *GET* is your action, the /car/{car id} is your thing, and the document it returns (and excepts via *POST* or *PUT* are the protocol of your API)